# Настройка Qt для работы с NDK android в Ubuntu 16.04 х64

Tags: qt, android-sdk, android-ndk

В интернете не нашёл ответа конкретно под Linux. Делал по [этой](http://blog.harrix.org/?p=2417) инструкции.
Имеется:

> QT Creator (Community)  Desktop Qt 5.6.0 GCC 64bit JDK location:
>
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 ANDROID SDK location:
>
> /home/alexandr/Android/Sdk ANDROID NDK location:
>
> /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/android-ndk-r11c ( установленна
>   переменная окружени JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 )
>
> AVD (API 14, armeabi-v7a) Kits Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt
>       5.6.0)

Проект шаблонный, созданный автоматически в Qt

При компиляции выдаёт

```
10:14:33: Running steps for project P2...
10:14:33: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
10:14:33: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
10:14:34: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
10:14:34: Removing directory /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-build/assets
10:14:34: Removing directory /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-build/libs
10:14:34: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" INSTALL_ROOT=/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-build install
install -m 755 -p libP2.so /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/libP2.so
10:14:35: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
10:14:35: Starting: "/home/alexandr/Qt/5.6/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" --input /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-libP2.so-deployment-settings.json --output /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-build --deployment bundled --android-platform android-23 --jdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 --gradle
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-libP2.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-build/
  Application binary: /home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/libP2.so
  Android build platform: android-23
  Install to device: No
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.buildToolsVersion is missing!
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:84)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groovy:467)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.access$0(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure9.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:372)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.444 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/alexandr/Documents/Job/_android/P2/build-P2-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_6_0-Debug/android-build/build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-build'.
> Invalid revision: 24.0.0-preview

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
10:14:43: The process "/home/alexandr/Qt/5.6/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project P2 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.6.0))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

Comment: Получилось запустить. Позже опишу подробности, пока напишу лишь, что работает с Qt 5.2.1 for android x86

Comment: Самая новая версия которая сработала Qt 5.3.2